# Make company names clickable in job searches

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Please make the company names clickable to the company page in the job searches:

[image]

Comment: Rather than putting an off-site link *riiiight* next to the primary link on the result, it might make more sense to only link these when there's an associated company page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our primary goal with this search result is to get you to the actual job listing. From there, we should make it easy to get to the company page/site or location information. I'm only worried that this will muddy the funnel of users searching > viewing jobs > applying (or looking for more information).

Once you've made it to the job, the company name links to either a company page or an external URL for the company.

This is related to and has received a similar answer to [Make location of job linkable to google map](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312732/make-location-of-job-linkable-to-google-map/314522#314522)