# Make location of job linkable to google map

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching for a job there is a little map indicator as shown:

[image]

Please make the city / map indicator linkable to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/companyName#locations

For instance, here's form fires locations:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/formfire#locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our primary goal with this search result is to get you to the actual job listing.  From there, we should make it easy to get to the company page/site or location information.  I'm only worried that this will muddy the funnel of users searching > viewing jobs > applying (or looking for more information).

This is related to and has received a similar answer to [Make company names clickable in job searches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312724/make-company-names-clickable-in-job-searches)

Comment: Honestly, a map with jobs marked on it would be a very useful thing for me. Commuting time is one of the major decision factors for me in choosing a job (seriously, I've turned down a £10k increase because it would have added 30 mins to my commute), so the map is the first thing I look at when I am deciding whether to apply or not. It's also the last thing you get to on the job page. Most of the roles I see listed are too far away, but it's not possible to see that until I've clicked the job, then click through to the company, then scrolled down. And I have to do that for every single one. :-(