# On job listing page, make Location a link to Google Maps to facilitate commute calculation

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

## Summary

When viewing a job listing page, I'd like for the job's Location field to be a link to a Google Map of that location. For reasons stated in the following **Motivation** section, it is particularly important that this Google Map has the Directions feature enabled. Some embedded Google Maps are configured to hide the Directions feature.

[image]
Bonus points if it links directly to a Google Maps Direction page starting from my Location (obtained from careers.stackoverflow.com CV) to the location of the employer.

## Motivation

One of my major considerations when job hunting is the commute. I live within 20 miles of 3 other states, and I don't necessarily know all the cities in those other states. Also, 20 miles down I-95 is different drive than 20 miles through Pennsylvania back roads.

## Difference from similar request

There is a similar request that was rejected.

[Make location of job linkable to google map](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312732/make-location-of-job-linkable-to-google-map)

My request is different as I am suggesting that the link goes on the actual job listing page, not the general search results page. This mitigates the objection made by Will Cole

> I'm only worried that this will muddy the funnel of users searching >
>   viewing jobs > applying (or looking for more information).

By placing the map link on the job listing page, the user has already been funneled through the *search phase*. In the *looking-for-more-information phase*, a commute-minded user will quickly seek the job's location in relation to his own (i.e. the commute time). For myself, and probably others, I will have made my decision not to  continue onto the *apply phase* if the commute is outside my desired range.

## Winners and Losers

- The user wins by saving time.
- The current employer wins and loses. They lose because they quickly lost a potential applicant, but they win because this applicant was probably not a good fit for them anyway due to the commute.
- The next employer in the search results wins because their job listing gets viewed more quickly by the applicant who just rejected a job that he knew was not a good fit.

## Current work-around

1. Copy/paste address into browser's Google search bar, or use Chrome's "Search Google For" context menu item.
2. Once initial search results appear, click the Maps tab on google.com
3. Once Google Maps page loads, click Directions button.
4. Click button to select my Current Location as the starting address for the directions.

Note: Implementing this feature request would eliminate steps 1-3, of this work-around. If the bonus points were also implemented, step 4 would also be eliminated.

Comment: Is "blue bell, pa" a sufficiently small location for it to be helpful to do this? most job ads I see just list a city which is practically useless if the city is of any size.

Comment: You bring up a good point. A job listing with a location on Pheonix, AZ is pretty useless for this feature. Employers are able to put their full address on their company page, so maybe the link could map right to that address. Blue Bell, PA is a pretty small place, 5.4 sq miles. And PA, NJ, MD are all dense with small cities like this.

Comment: I already asked for a similiar feature and it was status-declined.  But this one is in the job listing page and needs to be implemented ASAP.  This could be as simple as linking to: `https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=someAddress` For example, https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=6533+Sims+Dr+Sterling+Heights+MI also SO doesn't need to worry about driving directions from your current location, once you click the link I posted, google needs to know if it can use your location to allow for this feature.  Totally doable +1.

Comment: @JonH Yes, I actually referred to your request as part of mine. It sounds like you also prioritize commute in your job search. And you are correct, Google Maps has a "Current Location" button, which I mention in my work-around. Using the user's location from their CV data was just a bonus implementation feature that would save the user an extra button click. Also, the "Current Location" button is less accurate if the user is not currently at their primary residence, say they're job hunting while on vacation.

Comment: @WalterStabosz - True but these technical features can be implemented at a later time, I mean when you're on vacation you shouldn't be looking for a job - otherwise you aren't on vacation.  Point being, lets start small (baby steps) lets get the link going because that is VERY important...All the other bells and whistles can come later - if in fact they are needed.

Comment: @JonH :) ok no job hunting on vacation then, How about we change the hypothetical to: when you're far away from your family on a traveling consult gig halfway across the county

Comment: @WalterStabosz - Fine but first this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA9rvB-6vrA

Comment: Not to pile on, but to expand on TZHX's point, I've seen many employer's will fib about their actual city.  For instance, employers in a less-desirable suburb or off-the-beaten path will list their city as the nearby "hip" city, rather than the one on their mailing address.  I don't know how prevalent this is overall, but it's very common by me.